# does the chance of a player winning n games before another player increase with the size of n?

Tags: probability

If i know the probability of a player winning a game, and their are n games in a match, what is the probability of them winning n matches first (before the second player)?

Furthermore does their chance of winning decrease with the size of n?

thanks

Comment: It depends on what else you know about the player and how the game works.

Comment: i know the probabilty of them winning one game.

Comment: im not sure where to start with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each game is independent with a probability $p$ of Player A winning, than the probability of Player A winning $n$ games before losing $n$ games is the same as for playing $2n-1$ games and winning at least $n$ of them, which is $$\sum_{m=n}^{2n-1} {2n-1 \choose m}p^m (1-p)^{2n-1-m} = p^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {2n-1 \choose k}p^{n-k} (1-p)^{k}$$
and for $\frac12 \lt p \lt 1$ this is an increasing function of $n$, while for $0 \lt p \lt \frac12$ this is a decreasing function of $p$

Comment: thanks,for the sum does k go up by 1 each time?

Comment: Yes.  $k$ is the number of games that can be lost by player A: anything from $0$ through to $n-1$ (corrected from $n$)

Comment: after 6 games, the probability starts to decrease again, why would this be?

Comment: For what $p$ (and or $n$) do you say "after 6 games, the probability starts to decrease again"?

Comment: p of 0.8 and an n of 6, thanks

Comment: For $p=0.8$ and $n=5$ I get $0.9804186$.  For $p=0.8$ and $n=6$ I get $0.9883458$. For $p=0.8$ and $n=7$ I get $0.9929964$. This seems to be increasing with $n$

Comment: oh, i must be using the formula wrong, i am not good at this! So,  for say, n = 5, i am doing from k= 1 to k = 4, and then i sum them up at the end .

Comment: You need to start at $k=0$.  So for $p=0.8$ and $n=5$ the sum is $0.4096 \times (0.32768+ 0.73728+ 0.73728+ 0.43008+ 0.16128)$ i.e.  $0.13421773 +0.30198989 +0.30198989 +0.17616077 +0.06606029$ adding up to $0.9804186$

Comment: for 0.32768, i thought you cant divide by zero(for k) ?

Comment: You are dividing by $0!=1$ not $0$ so $\displaystyle {2n-1 \choose 0} = \dfrac{(2n-1)!}{0!\, (2n-1)!}=1$ for all positive integers $n$.  These are part of the left hand set of $1$s in Pascal's triangle

Comment: ohh, thank you sooo much :)

Comment: would the top 2n-1 and the bottom 2n-1 cancel out?

Comment: Yes-ish: when $k=0$ the factorial $(2n-1)!$ cancels from the numerator and denominator

Comment: do you know what this wole equation is called by any chance?